# Suppose $f(z) = u+iv$ is holomorphic and it's not zero in a domain $\Omega$. Use the following equality to prove that $u$ and $v$ are harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The equality involves the laplacian operator, and is the following: $$\Delta(|f(z)|)=\frac{|f'(z)|^2}{|f(z)|}$$

In my attempt to prove this, I setted $z=x+iy$, $f=u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$  and $|f(z)|=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ and then calculated $\Delta(\sqrt{u^2+v^2})$

I managed to get to $$\Delta(|f(z)|)=\frac{|f'(z)|^2}{|f(z)|} + \frac{u(u_{xx}+u_{yy})+v(v_{xx}+v_{yy})}{|f|}$$

This means $u(u_{xx}+u_{yy})+v(v_{xx}+v_{yy})=0$. We have a couple of solutions here:

$$\begin{cases}u=0 \land \Delta v=0\\v=0 \land \Delta u=0\\ \Delta v=0 \land \Delta u=0
\end{cases}$$

All of these implies that $\Delta u =\Delta v=0$, which is what we want. The Following cases doesn't happen:

$$\begin{cases}u=0 \land \Delta v=0\\v=-u \land \Delta u=\Delta v\\v=u \land \Delta u=-\Delta v
\end{cases}$$

And the next two cases are the ones i'm having trouble with, because i don't know how to tackle this:

$$\begin{cases}u=-\Delta v \land v=\Delta u\\v=-\Delta u \land u=\Delta v
\end{cases}$$

Everywhere I go I get a high-order PDE, which is probably not the way to solve this. Any idea how to solve this or a tip for a different way to tackle this problem will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is also simply $u\Delta u = -v\Delta v$ without any of your listed cases being true. There is no rule that guarantees you can break it up as you have.

Comment: @PaulSinclair All these possibilities come from the equality $u\Delta u=−v\Delta v$. Does the result of $\Delta v = \Delta u = 0$ comes directly from the equality? If so, how?

Comment: No that result does not come directly from the equality. You'll have to be more creative. I haven't looked at it and am not offering a solution. I just pointed out that your break down of cases is not complete. Even if you handle the remaining cases, you will not have proven the result, because you will not have exhausted the possibilities. Add my case and you will have, but only because my case is just a minor rewriting of the orignal equality. It handles all the others by itself. I.e., you are currently barking up the wrong tree and need to do something else.